# How to make a custom sorting query in spring boot for a mongo db repository?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, repository

I want to put this query with `@Query` annotation in my repository.

This is the query:

```
`db.report.find({'company' : 'Random'}).sort( { 'reportDate' : -1} ).limit(1)`
```

Which is the best way to implement custom queries with @Query annotations or to use MongoTemplate ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using Mongo Template.

```
Criteria find = Criteria.where("company").is("Random");
Query query = new Query().addCriteria(find).with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "reportDate"));
BasicDBObject result = mongoOperations.findOne(query, BasicDBObject.class, "collection_name");
```

Using Mongo Repository

```
Report findTopByCompanyOrderByReportDateDesc(String company)
```

Comment: For newer versions, use Sort.by(Direction.DESC, "fieldName"), because Sort constructor is private now.

Answer (score 4):

Note that in the new version of Springboot(v2.2.5), the correct method is sort.by().
like this:

```
Query query = new Query().addCriteria(find).with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "reportDate"));
```

Comment: Worked Thanks! There are other similar questions still referring old versions.