# Spring Data REST "findBy..." not sorting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring Boot API (using 2.0.5.RELEASE spring-boot-starter-parent) and I'm using the spring-boot-starter-rest package to generate the endpoints for my API. In one of the repositories I have the following method:

```
@Repository
public interface RackPositionDao extends JpaRepository<RackPosition, String> {
    List<RackPosition> findByRack(@Param("rack") Rack rack);
}
```

Which exposes an endpoint at http://{base}/api/v1/rackPositions/findByRack

If I then call

> http://{base}/api/v1/rackPositions/findByRack?rack={rack
>   url}&sort=positionNumber,asc

in Postman, the list returned isn't sorted. 'positionNumber' is a property on the RackPosition entity.

However if I change the repository method to

```
@Repository
public interface RackPositionDao extends JpaRepository<RackPosition, String> {
    List<RackPosition> findByRackOrderByPositionNumberAsc(@Param("rack") Rack rack);
}
```

and then call

> http://{base}/api/v1/rackPositions/findByRackOrderByPositionNumberAsc?rack={rack
>   url}

it works fine. Is there a reason why the sort parameter doesn't work?

Comment: I have always used the `findBy...OrderBy..` interfaces - where have you seem that a `sort` parameter would work?

Comment: try changing `http://{base}/api/v1/rackPositions/findByRack?rack={rack url}&sort=positionNumber,asc` to `http://{base}/api/v1/rackPositions/search/rack?rack={rack url}&sort=positionNumber,asc`

Comment: @ScaryWombat [it works](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/paging-chapter.html)

Comment: @MatthewSatti As described at the bottom of [this page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/paging-chapter.html), you shouldn't use the `findBy` part in the URL, and the structure of the URL looks a bit different

Comment: @Kartik Glad I can come here and learn

Comment: If you try with url : http://{base}/api/v1/rackPositions/findByRack?rack={rack url}&sort=positionNumber&positionNumber.dir=asc ??

Comment: @Kartik I tried your suggestion and I got a 404 error. It seems it uses the full name of the repository method rather than truncating the 'findBy' part. Is this something that needs to be set up manually or should this be auto-configured?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41806931/2471528

Comment: @TinyOS That doesn't work either. I also tried http://{base}/api/v1/rackPositions?sort=positionNumber&positionNumber.dir=asc which will sort the list ascending, but if I specify desc, it will still sort the list ascending which is why I used the sort={property},{dir} syntax

Comment: @darshakat I understand I can get it to work by renaming the repository method, but my question is why doesn't it work via URL.

Comment: @MatthewSatti if you need to use via URL, just replace the JpaRepository with PagingAndSortingRepository, Then, this will work. PagingAndSortingRepository by default support sort. If you want to use JpaRepository, 
you must implement like:   

<S extends T> List<S> findAll(Example<S> example, Sort sort)
Refer below for more info:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html?is-external=true

Comment: @darshakat Changing the method signature to <S extends RackPosition> List<S> findByRack(@Param("rack") Rack rack, Sort sort); solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html

```
<S extends T> List<S> findAll(Example<S> example, Sort sort)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to sort result in Spring data JPA

1. Using Custom JPA Query as below

   `@Query("Select r from rack order by position_number ASC")`
2. Using JPA custom methods (as you used : `findByRackOrderByPositionNumberAsc`())
3. Passing Sort object in repository method as below

   `List<RackPosition> findByRack(@Param("rack") Rack rack,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort sort);`

and call the method as below

```
Sort sort = new Sort(new Sort.Order(Direction.ASC, "lastName"));
Object obj  = repo.findByRack(rackObject, sort);
```

Comment: Just a note that the above Constructor (`Sort(Order... orders)`) is deprecated by Spring 2.1.3, so use this instead:
`Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "lastName");`

Answer (score 0):

JpaRepository interface extends [PagingAndSortingRepository interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html).

So, you can use endpoint as
`http://{base}/api/v1/rackPositions/findbyRack` or `http://{base}/api/v1/rackPositions/find-byRack`
by avoiding camel caps.